# Converting AM/PM Time to epoch

Tags: python, date, datetime, epoch

I'm trying to convert a string date to epoch, but it doesn't seem to pick up the am or pm.  The time always defaults to am.

I've tried this:

```
dt = '2015-05-04 5:55PM'
pattern = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M%p'
epochDate = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(dt, pattern)))
print epochDate

# Result
1430684700

# Checking output
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1430684700).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%p')

# Doesn't show PM
'2015-05-04 05:55:00AM'
```

I'm not sure what I've done wrong here?

Comment: it will work fine if you just change `%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S%p`

Comment: yeah change the `%H` in both pattern and strftime to `%I`

Comment: Awesome... that works.  I didn't find the duplicate question.  Thank you for your help everybody.  I guess I need to delete this question?

Comment: No need to delete the question, the system will take care of it eventually if necessary. And sometimes it's useful to have differently worded questions if it helps future searchers.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the [`python-dateutil`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil) library:

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> dateutil.parser.parse('2015-05-04 5:55PM')
datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 4, 17, 55)
>>> dateutil.parser.parse('2015-05-04 5:55AM')
datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 4, 5, 55)
```